# Jquery hide/show scroll animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When I click on any year column (2012, 2011, 2010, etc) it shows the content of each year and hide the other ones.

The problem it's that when I click (2011 column for example), the animation does all the effects at the same time confusing the user, I think I have to do it with animation steps, but I haven't been able to come to a jquery solution.

This is my code:

```
/* Scroll Function */
function scrollto(position){
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: position
    }, 1000);
}

/* Calendar Scroll */
$(".sub_section_title").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".contenido_calendario").hide();
    $(this).next(".contenido_calendario").toggle('slow');
    scrollto($(this).offset().left - 352)
});
```

I have tried fixing the effect by using .queue() but it doesn't work, I don't know if the code it's well written also:

```
$(".sub_section_title").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".contenido_calendario").hide();
    $(".contenido_calendario").queue(function() {
        scrollto($(this).offset().left - 352);
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
    $(".contenido_calendario").queue(function() {
        $(this).next(".contenido_calendario").toggle('slow')
    $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

The animation should be: 
Click 2011 > Scroll 2011 column to the left (hide 2012 content) > show animation of contents

Answer (score 2):

You want to take advantage of the callback features of the jQuery animations.  So for [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), for example, you could do:

```
var outerContainer = $(this);
$(".contenido_calendario").hide(500, function() {
    outerContainer.next(".contenido_calendario").toggle('slow', function() {
        scrollto(outerContainer.offset().left - 352);
    });
});
```

This will ensure that the animations are run when the previous one is finished.

Comment: hehe ok, I changed it but look what it does now

Comment: @FxG would removing the scrollTo fix that?  I'm not entirely sure what the animation you're going for is.

Comment: The animation should be: 
Click 2011 > Scroll 2011 column to the left (hide 2012 content) > show animation of contents